# How can I use Python to decode a rs 232 capture (trace)

Tags: python-2.7, trace

I'm attempting to use Python (2.7) to decode a trace I captured with a FrontLine-ComProbe USB rs232 device. I tried:

```
import binascii

my_file = open('c:\\My_Trace.cfa', 'r')

aString = my_file.read()

comp = binascii.b2a_qp(aString)
```

I'm not getting the ascii I was expecting; it's non-human readable text. Can someone please give me direction .... Thanks!

Comment: Can you upload the file `My_Trace.cfa` somewhere?

Comment: `open('c:\\My_Trace.cfa', 'rb')` binary read is important when you decode aferwards.